# How can I pass the contents of a tstringstream to a method that takes in an LPTSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stream, type-conversion, stringstream

I have tried the following:

```
tstringstream s;
s << _T("test") << std::endl;
LPTSTR message = s.str().c_str();
Log(5, _T("Example", message);
```

Where Log is defined as such:

```
void Log(DWORD dwSeverity, LPTSTR szAppID, LPTSTR szMsgString, ...)
{

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: A value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPTSTR"
```

But I'm not sure exactly how to handle this conversion. In my case, I am compiling a multi-byte character-set application using the MSVC++ compiler. Under these conditions, LPTSTR is defined as an LPSTR, which is defined as a CHAR *.

Comment: The posted code has a dangling pointer (named `message`), as the `std::string` object which returns the `char*` via `c_str()` is destructed at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems.

First of all here:

```
LPTSTR message = s.str().c_str();
```

The call to `s.str()` returns a temporary which will be destroyed unless you keep it alive. Therefore the address returned by calling `c_str()` becomes invalid. You need a temporary local:

```
string str = s.str();
LPCTSTR message = str.c_str();
```

And since `c_str()` returns a const C string, you need to declare message to be a const C string too.

The other problem is that your `Log` function receives a non-const C string, but `c_str()` returns a const C string. Presumably the `Log` function does not need to modify the message, so why are you asking for a modifiable buffer. Change `Log` to receive a const C string:

```
void Log(..., LPCTSTR szMsgString, ...)
```

Finally, since this is C++, why are you using C strings at all? It is better to use C++ strings.

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting `const`-incompatibility. For some reason, the function `Log` takes a pointer to mutable data, which is incompatible with the pointer to `const` data returned by `c_str()`.

If you have the option, change `Log` to take its parameter as `const` (I assume it does not actually modify the string passed in):

```
void Log(DWORD dwSeverity, LPCTSTR szAppID, LPCTSTR szMsgString, ...)
```

The same way, declare `message` as `LPCTSTR`.

Also note that you cannot actually initialise `message` the way you're doing it now: the string returned by `str()` is temporary, so you have to store it:

```
tstring message = s.str();
Log(5, _T("Example", message.c_str());
```

If `Log` is outside your control, but you **know** that it **does not modify** its arguments, you can use a `const_cast`:

```
LPTSTR message = const_cast<LPTSTR>(message.c_str());  // `message` changed as above
```

If you cannot vouch for what `Log` does internally, you'll have to create a mutable buffer:

```
std::vector<TCHAR> buffer(message.begin(), message.end());
buffer.push_back(0);
Log(5, _T("Example", &buffer[0]);
```